# luasocket send UDP data from port 1900

Tags: sockets, lua, udp, luasocket

I am trying to Emulate Belkin wemo switch from my Home automation controller to send voice command from amazon Echo.The controller supports lua language.

I am following up this [file](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/fauxmo/latest/fauxmo.pdf) to send the UDP data from port 1900 of Controller to port 50000 of Echo. right now every time i send the data the Socket take the random port send data not from port 1900. Echo only make valid connection and reply if the data comes from the port 1900. I am scratching my head from last two days to make is work but havent figured it out yet.

Bellow is my code.

```
strData1 =
  'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' .. 
 'HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900'..
 'CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=100'..
 'EXT:'..
 'LOCATION: http://192.168.1.152:49153/description.xml'..
 'SERVER: Linux/3.14.0 UPnP/1.0 IpBridge/1.19.0'..
 'hue-bridgeid: B8AC6FFFFEC53475'..
 'ST: upnp:rootdevice'..
 'USN: uuid:2f402f80-da50-11e1-9b23-b8ac6fc53475::upnp:rootdevice'

 local socket = require "socket"
 local udp = socket.udp()

 udp:settimeout(0)
 udp:setsockname('*', 1900)
 udp:setpeername('192.168.1.102', 50000) -- Echo IP and Port number
 udp:sendto(strData1,'192.168.1.102',50000)
```

Comment: First, I suggest you wrap all the `udp` function calls in `assert` in order to be sure that everything works fine. Second, you have set the timeout value to `0`, which means that it'll timeout every time. Set it to a positive value `udp:settimeout(1)` or to nil if you want it to block indefinitely.

Comment: changed the udp:settimeout(1) dint helped. Also put assert now i got the error it says "address already in use" when setting socket name(udp:setsockname('*', 1900)). How can i close the socket if system is running any?

Comment: Based on [this](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/reference.html) you have to use the `close` function. Also, I suggest you use that function in conjuction with `select` in order to get a list with the sockets ready for reading and a list with the sockets ready for writing.

Comment: @kingJulian where is “select” function?

Comment: It's in the link but let's take this over to the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163397/room-for-kingjulian-and-prakash-dti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there: the [documentation](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/udp.html#setpeername) states that when using `setpeername`, `send` must be used instead of `sendto`.

Also, I guess it was a typo, but you are trying to send `Data` instead of `strData1`. Here is the corrected version:

```
strData1 =
  'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' .. 
 'HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900'..
 'CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=100'..
 'EXT:'..
 'LOCATION: http://192.168.1.152:49153/description.xml'..
 'SERVER: Linux/3.14.0 UPnP/1.0 IpBridge/1.19.0'..
 'hue-bridgeid: B8AC6FFFFEC53475'..
 'ST: upnp:rootdevice'..
 'USN: uuid:2f402f80-da50-11e1-9b23-b8ac6fc53475::upnp:rootdevice'

 local socket = require "socket"
 local udp = socket.udp()

 udp:settimeout(0)
 udp:setoption('reuseaddr',true)
 udp:setsockname('*', 1900)
 udp:setpeername('192.168.1.102', 50000) -- Echo IP and Port number
 udp:send(strData1)
```

Tcpdump's capture shows that the source port is correct:

`22:40:45.653222 IP my.super.secret.ip.1900 > 192.168.1.102.50000: UDP, length 280`

Comment: You don't supply the IP:port to `send()`. The rule about send/sendto is strange. You can use either at the BSD Sockets level, but if connected you just don't supply the IP:port to `sendto()`: just a null address pointer. Maybe that's not possible in LUA source.

Comment: I am getting error on this line “ udp:setsockname('*', 1900)”. It’s says “already running sockets on Port 1900”. I have not created any socket on port 1900.i don’t know the socket name so I cannot use the close() function. How can I get list of running socket? Or can we force close socket on port 1900? I can’t find anything in API:(

Comment: @Prakash.DTI You *must* use the close function, and make whatever adjustments are necessary to make it possible.

Comment: Normally we close the Socket that we initiated earlier like...   udp = socket.udp()then we use the udp:close() to close the socket but the system that am working on is a linux home automation controller when i execute "udp:setsockname('*', 1900)" it says that socket already running on that Port. How do i get the Socket name to use the close() function on it?

Comment: @Prakash.DTI what’s the output of netstat -laputen?

Comment: udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1900            0.0.0.0:*                   3970/director
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1900            0.0.0.0:*                   3970/director
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1900            0.0.0.0:*                   3473/sysmand
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1900            0.0.0.0:*                   3382/c4server
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1902            0.0.0.0:*                   3970/director

Comment: It looks like you have a daemon listening on that port already. Either bind your private ip (rather than *) in the lua file, or make the daemon listen on a dedicated ip. Or to make it simpler, just kill those processes for your testing purpose.

Comment: if i do private ip like this..                                                                                          `local socket = require "socket"
udp= socket.udp()
assert(udp:settimeout(1))
assert(udp:setsockname('192.168.1.106', 1900))`                                                                                     Output:address already in use

Comment: `udp:setoption('reuseaddr',true)` is the solution. this will enable to use one port with Multiple Socket.  @Aif for pointing me in right direction.  Please also add this line to your answer.

Comment: This is not working when using the TCP connection. even after setting the option 'reuseaddr'to 'true'i am getting 'address already in use' error. I know there is ngix server running on Port 80 but like my previous UDP connection how can i run two thread on same Port 80? 
 `local socket = require "socket"
    local tcp = socket.tcp()
    local ControllersIP = C4: GetControllerNetworkAddress()
    tcp:settimeout(5)
    tcp:setoption('reuseaddr',true)
    assert(tcp:setsockname(ControllersIP, 80))
    tcp:setpeername(EchoIP, 50000) 
    tcp:send(file)
    tcp:close()`